# WooCommerce Different Stock Numbers for Product Variations

Tags: woocommerce

Currently have a setup where I want to be able to manage stock on WooCommerce.

So say I have a single product with 3 Variations (small, medium, large). The way the is arranged is the small option dispenses 1 piece, medium 2 pieces, and large 3 pieces of the same product.

Now say I have 100 pieces of inventory stock. When a user buys a size small I want this to deduct 1 piece from the total stock, but when a user buyers the size large, I need this to deduct 3 pieces from the total stock number.

Currently unable to figure out a way to make this happen. Any advance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!